# Transaction waits forever for InnoDB Lock

Tags: mysql, timeout, locking, innodb

I'm working with innoDB blocks, I'm trying to emulate the problem I'm having in my production server. When trying to insert a row in a "transaction" table in MYSQL.

I locked the table using this command:

```
LOCK TABLES transaction AS tran WRITE;
```

After that I create a transaction from my web app, and the transaction is kept blocked by the lock. The problem is that this transaction is blocked forever.

I can see it in MYSQL waiting by runnning this command:

```
show full processlist;
```

And just stays there.

I changed the MYSQL variable *innodb_lock_wait_timeout* to 10 secs  but never fails.

This is the response in the process list:

```
Waiting for table metadata lock
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't lock the entire table: of course the transaction will be locked forever. You should instead create a first transaction that will lock the second you'll run. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-lock-modes.html#idm140073906446176 for example

Answer (score 0):

> After that I tried to create a transaction from my web app, and the
>   transaction is kept blocked by the lock. The problem is that this
>   transaction is blocked forever.

Please show your code: lock and insert

[LOCK TABLES and UNLOCK TABLES Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html)

> LOCK TABLES explicitly acquires table locks for the current client
>   session. Table locks can be acquired for base tables or (as of MySQL
>   5.0.6) views. You must have the LOCK TABLES privilege, and the SELECT 
>   privilege for each object to be locked. UNLOCK TABLES explicitly
>   releases any table locks held by the current session. LOCK TABLES
>   implicitly releases any table locks held by the current session before
>   acquiring new locks.
>
> Another use for UNLOCK TABLES is to release the global read lock
>   acquired with the FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK statement, which enables
>   you to lock all tables in all databases.
>
> A table lock protects only against inappropriate reads or writes by
>   other sessions. The session holding the lock, even a read lock, can
>   perform table-level operations such as DROP TABLE. Truncate operations
>   are not transaction-safe, so an error occurs if the session attempts
>   one during an active transaction or while holding a table lock.

Did you see [Configurable InnoDB Auto-Increment Locking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-auto-increment-configurable.html)
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode ?

```
mysql> UNLOCK TABLES;
        Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELETE  FROM `shop`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> LOCK TABLES shop AS tran WRITE READ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO shop AS tran VALUES (1,'A',3.45);
        ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS tran VALUES (1,'A',3.45)' at line 1
Imysql> INSERT INTO tran VALUES (1,'A',3.45);
        ERROR 1100 (HY000): Table 'tran' was not locked with LOCK TABLES
mysql> INSERT INTO shop  VALUES (1,'A',3.45);
        ERROR 1100 (HY000): Table 'shop' was not locked with LOCK TABLES
mysql>
mysql> UNLOCK TABLES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
D
mysql> DELETE  FROM `shop`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: The insertion code is not really important as it's doing what it's supposed, try to insert. What I really want to know is why this insert is held there forever. It's supposed to return a fail by lock_timeout no? I belive it's more a MYSql issue.

Comment: I added execution which has problem with LOCK TABLES transaction AS tran WRITE;

Comment: what do yo mean by add a execution?

Comment: I added sample, where your syntax not work. Please add pure SQL, or code.